# How to concatenate list of arrays into list of matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I've got 3  np.array of each row has a size 3

```
A = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]] 
B = [[4,5,6],[5,6,7]]
C = [[7,8,9],[8,9,0]]
```

and I want to get efficiently a list of Matrices that concatenate each rows of the lists :

```
Mat = [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,0]]]
```

I presume that I must use in a clever way np.concatenate, but I cannot catch the way to do that.

Comment: `list(zip(A, B, C))` or `list(map(list, zip(A, B, C)))` *(if you want elements of outer list to be lists as well)*

Comment: Thanks. And if I want to get the list of tranposes ?

Comment: Play with the axis parameter in np.stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
import numpy as np
A = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
B = [[4,5,6],[5,6,7]]
C = [[7,8,9],[8,9,0]]

D = np.concatenate(np.array([A,B,C]),axis = 1).reshape(-1,3,3)
```

This will produce `array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,0]]])`

Answer (score 0):

```
np.column_stack([A,B,C]).reshape(2,3,3)
```

or

```
np.column_stack([A,B,C]).reshape(2,3,3).tolist()
```

should do the trick.